# determining the properties of pores

Tags: matlab, image-processing, imagej

I have several series of segmented images and I need to calculate the properties (area, perimeter, radius of the largest circle fitting in area) of the black areas (pores). I could not find the value with the software imagej as it seems that it has some problems in distinguishing the holes (569 area was found) and I tried to find the values by **regionprops** in matlab. however, it seems that it has the same problem (570 area was found). So, can anybody please help me find the solution to this question?
here is the areas found by imagej.

[image: original]
[image: numbered_areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black regions bleed into one another and ImageJ cannot distinguish them. If you use `Process > Binary > Watershed`, this will segregate the regions into (most likely) separate objects. Be aware that you may need to invert the image before doing this. Then you can use `Analyze > Analyze Particles...` to find the objects. The measurements that ImageJ produces can be controlled using `Set Measurements` and in the dialog for `Analyze Particles`. It will do area and perimeter for each object, but not (AFAIK) the radius of the largest circle.

Comment: That's it. Wow. Thanks a lot I mean A LOT LOT.

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) for more information